# Get-AdUsers in a for-each loop with appended characters in powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm trying to get a (one line) answer to get a list of users (based on a filter of get-aduser) then use that list to do a search matching on an extended version of their name - e.g. I have:

- UserA
- UserB
- UserAAdmin
- UserBAdmin

and want to find (when user A is disabled) the UserAAdmin. This seemed like it would be simple, but I can't seem to use the SAMACCOUNTNAME with a like or equals statement no matter what I try- i.e.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -Properties sAMAccountName |
ForEach {Get-AdUser -Filter {samaccountname -like ($_.samaccountname + "Admin")}}
```

(as for the why, well, because the client I'm working with has a structure such that all their user accounts have ADMIN added to the end of their admin accounts and we want to find any disabled USER accounts and find (and then disable) the associated admin account).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of Avshalom is correct, but it is not efficient and useless to queries your AD twice ...
Once you have all your disabled users then you can just filter

```
 $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}
Foreach ($User in $Users)
    {
    $Match = "ADM-"+$User.SamAccountName
    $Users|?{$_.samaccountname -like $match}


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you right, you can try this...

```
$DisabledUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}
Foreach ($User in $DisabledUsers)
    {
    $Match = $User.SamAccountName + '*'
    $MatchedUsers = Get-AdUser -Filter {samaccountname -like $match}

        foreach ($MatchUser in $MatchedUsers)
        {
        "You Can do here what you want"
        }
    }
```